# how to get the element a[@id='ks-overlay-close-ks-component9045'], and the div[@id='ks-component9045'] is Popup window

Tags: python, selenium-firefoxdriver

[Picture: there is Popup window in the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjNO6.png)

```
    try:
        all_handles = self.driver.window_handles
        for handle in all_handles:
            if handle != now_handle:
                print handle
                try:
                    self.driver.switch_to_window(handle)
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ks-overlay-close-ks-component9045']").click()
                except:
                    continue
```

but it is failed, i can not switch to the window and close it

Answer (score 0):

This one does not look like a browser pop up window. In this case you don't need switch_to_window and window_handles functions, just find the DOM element that represents the close button and have click on it.